# Intermediate step of the recurrence relation T(n) = 2T(n/2)+ n/log(n)

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, relation, recurrence

I need help understanding one intermediate step in solving the following recurrence relation:

[image]

Through repeated substitution I have gotten all the way up to:

[image]

This is where I am stuck. Everyone says that the second part is equal to

[image]

I have tried much manipulation and I cannot figure out how to get here.

**So - two questions:**

1. Why is the bounds on the sum going from 1 to *log(n)*?
2. How do you arrive at this summation from the sequence that I have? I know the sequence is also written as

[image]

I don't need the solution to the entire recurrence, I know exactly how to solve it from there, just this intermediate step.

Comment: I think this question would fit better on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all such recurrences are solved with [Master's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). You asked why so here is an explanation.

First question was why do you sum from `1` to `log n`. Its easy: you start with a number n and each time you reduces it by `2` times. So how fast will it approach to `n`? After `log n` times (`log` means `log2` here). If this is not clear substitute your `n` with `2^k`.

Now the second part. Your i-th element is (If the these elementary log operations are not clear for you, you have to refresh your knowledge on logarithms):

[image]

Now it should be clear why your solution is equivalent to theirs.

Comment: As for your answer to number 2, I dont have a problem with those steps, I am more of trying to understand why they equate that to sum from 1 to logn of 1/k (a harmonic series)

Answer (score 1):

You've unfolded your recurrence *k* times to get to

[image]

Which means that *n = 2<sup>k</sup>* so:

1. logging both sides of this equation means *log(n) = log(2<sup>k</sup>) = k* which answers why the summation bound goes to *log(n)*
2. substitute for *n* into each term of the summation and you get:

[image]

Finally:

[image]

The two sides just write the harmonic series in reverse order of eachother.